# SQL Server stored procedure or function has too many arguments specified, when trying to pass 2 arguments in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to execute a stored procedure called `getLastFeatureUpdate`.

I will explain below the problem, step by step:

I have created a table in SQL like this:

```
CREATE TABLE testTable
(
      DayTime INT     NOT NULL, /*yyddhhmm, 1010102345*/
      FeatureNbr      SMALLINT  NOT NULL,
      Val FLOAT(53)   NOT NULL
);
```

I have now created a stored procedure called `getLastFeatureUpdate`. Important to notice here is that I use 2 parameters `@maxDateTime` and `@tableName`, as those are different each time. So I will then pass in those 2 parameters in the C# code that follows in the end.

The stored procedure (if I remove `@tableName text` from the procedure and the C# code. Then the code does work to mention)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getLastFeatureUpdate
    @maxDateTime float(53) = 0,
    @tableName text
AS
    SELECT
        test.FeatureNbr,
        test.DayTime,
        test.Val
    FROM
        @tableName test 
    WHERE
        DayTime = (SELECT MAX(DayTime)
                   FROM @tableName
                   WHERE FeatureNbr = test.FeatureNbr --This is what you are missing
                     AND DayTime <= @maxDateTime)   --10102248
```

The C# code where I want to return the data from `testTable`. Which are shown in: `MessageBox.Show(d1 + "," + d2 + "," + d3);`

But here is where I get the error:

> Procedure or function getLastFeatureUpdate has too many arguments specified

Notice, that if I don't pass on the 2nd row here with `@tableName`, the code will work (I then have to remove `@tableName` as a parameter also in the stored  procedure `getLastFeatureUpdate`)

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@maxDateTime", 10102248));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@tableName", "testTable")); //If not using this parameter, the code will work
```

C# code:

```
void getLastFeatureUpdate()
{
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString()))
        {
            conn.Open();

            // 1. create a command object identifying the stored procedure
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("getLastFeatureUpdate", conn);

            // 2. set the command object so it knows to execute a stored procedure
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            // 3. add parameter to command, which will be passed to the stored procedure
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@maxDateTime", 10102248));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@tableName", "testTable")); //If not using this parameter, the code will work

            // execute the command
            using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                // iterate through results, printing each to console
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    int v1 = (int)rdr["DayTime"];
                    int v2 = (Int16)rdr["FeatureNbr"];
                    double v3 = (double)rdr["Val"];

                    MessageBox.Show(v1 + "," + v2 + "," + v3);
                }
            }
        }
}

static private string GetConnectionString()
{
    return "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\andre\\source\\repos\\TestDatabaseCreation\\DatabaseTest.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
}
```

Comment: Do not use the text datatype as it is depreciated past SQL Server 2005. You should use varchar or nvarchar instead.

Comment: Nolan that is great. Good you mentioned that. I will change that then.

Comment: Do NOT store dates or datetimes as numbers. This path only leads you to future problems and more work - much more work. And if you had experimented even a little, you would have discovered why you cannot use INT to store the sample value in your comment.

Comment: And your comment regarding DayTime column is incorrect - it's YYYYMMDDHHMM (or perhaps YYYYDDMM...)? Can't really say since there is nothing to constrain the values at all to valid dates and times.

Comment: SMor, you are right about the `int`, it can't take the `YYYYMMDDHHMM `. Initially I had only `YYMMDDHHMM ` in my test code. I will change my post. I must remember this for the datetime numbers to not use int as well later.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot parameterize the table name in SQL Server, so: that SQL is invalid, and the `CREATE PROC` did not in fact run. What the contents of the old proc are: only you can know, but: it isn't the code shown. It was probably a dummy version you had at some point in development. Try typing:

```sql
exec sp_helptext getLastFeatureUpdate;
```

Specifically, the server should have told you:

```
Msg 1087, Level 16, State 1, Procedure getLastFeatureUpdate, Line 12 [Batch Start Line 0]
Must declare the table variable "@tableName".
Msg 1087, Level 16, State 1, Procedure getLastFeatureUpdate, Line 19 [Batch Start Line 0]
Must declare the table variable "@tableName".
```

Comment: I understand but I wonder how it would be possible for the `Stored Procedure` to know on which table this command should be executed on if it is not possible to pass on this as an argument? For example I could have 100 different tables.

Comment: A beginner question here: I am not sure when I should execute that command in Visual Studio? `exec sp_helptext getLastFeatureUpdate;`

Comment: @coding bad news: "it isn't (possible)" - you're not *meant* to have stored procedures that are parameterized by table. Any way you slice it, you're going to end up concatenating strings here, which is just begging for SQL injection problems. I strongly recommend you reconsider your approach.

Comment: @coding for executing SQL, you probably want to use SSMS, not Visual Studio

Comment: Oh that is bad news because the software would create tables dynamically in C# when it needs to. Then those tables would need a Stored Procedure. Is it true that those procedures must be hardcoded one by one for each table. Is this the only way?

Comment: I think I must use Visual Studio as my whole main software is created there and I now "just" need the SQL database for this software.

Comment: If the application creates tables, etc, when it needs to, @coding, it would use suitably prepared statements, not a stored procedure that tries to use a scalar variable as a replacement for a literal object name.

Comment: @coding question; why do you even need a stored procedure here? but: creating large numbers of tables at runtime is *usually* a sign of something very wrong in a design; there *are* times when it is valid, but that's not how most applications are intended to function; you will, ultimately, have to resort to composing SQL at runtime under such a model. That can be done in SQL or C# (or anything else), but it carries an inherent risk of SQL Injection if you don't get it absolutely right

Comment: Larnu You mean that I should use the approach like this: `SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("Write the Query here")` ? With other words pass the query as a string instead?

Comment: Marc, yes I am so new to the SQL so I just thought of making Stored Procedures felt good instead of doing "string" Queries. But I am learning. I should not use it for this purpose then. A few tables will be created at runtime. As a simple example to understand. If adding "cars" in the software, "football", "basket", "cricket" etc, then a new table will be created that only have information about each of the topics as it happens quite dynamically and at anytime.